# Extract the node from BST, preserving the fake node

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, binary-search-tree

I am writing a binary search tree (BST) with bidirectional iterator. To present .end() I have "fake node", that is the rightest son of the tree. I have problem with extract: my code works incorrectly whenever it gets to "fake node". I made a flag in the node, in order to mark it as fake one, but I just don't know, how to check this condition. I tried placing several "if" statements, but they didn't work. Can anybody help me with that??
Here is my code:

```
node_type* ExtractHelper(node_type* root, Key key) {
        if (root == nullptr) {
            return root;
        } else if (key < root->value) {
            root->left = ExtractHelper(root->left, key);
        } else if (key > root->value) {
            root->right = ExtractHelper(root->right, key);
        } else {
            if (root->left == nullptr) {
                value_type* temp = root->right;
                DeleteNode(root);
                if (temp) {
                    temp->parent = root->parent;
                }
                return temp;
            } else if (root->right == nullptr) {
                value_type* temp = root->left;
                DeleteNode(root);
                if (temp) {
                    temp->parent = root->parent;
                }
                return temp;
            }
            value_type* temp = GetLeftest(root->right);
            root->value = temp->value;
            root->right = ExtractHelper(root->right, temp->value);
        }
        return root;
    }
```

i tried writing something like this:

```
if (temp) {
    temp->parent = cur->parent;
    temp->right = cur->right;
    cur->right->parent = temp
}
```

but this doesn't work. So I am actually waiting for suggestion of some modifications.

Comment: Nothing in this code makes use of iterators or `end`?

Comment: ExtractHelper - what is this function supposed to do?

Comment: *"my code works incorrectly whenever it gets to 'fake node'."* -- By this, you mean when your code gets to the "fake node", it starts downloading cat videos? (Pretty sure that falls under "working incorrectly"). Could you be more specific than "doesn't work"? What are the symptoms? What did you observe that led you to believe the code does not work? (The closer you can come to a [mre], the better.)

Comment: Regarding "STL": You could write a container in the style of STL, but unless you plan to resurrect the library, your new creation will not be part of the library.

Comment: If `DeleteNode` does what I think it does, surely doing `root->parent = ...` afterwards is a crash waiting to happen?

Comment: Side note, "fake node" is usually called a "sentinel node". You might look that up.

Comment: What is the difference between `node_type` and `value_type`? Why is `temp` not `node_type*` since it is assigned a `node_type*`? Also, does `Delete(root)` free the memory of `root*`? If so, then it is undefined behaviour to still reference `root->parent` after that...

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this problem by construction by making sure that `end()` returns a node that will never be part of any BST:

```
static node_type _end;
node_type* end() const { return &_end; }
node_type* end() { return &_end; }
node_type* cend() const { return &_end; }
```

You need to also override the `operator++` and `operator--` of your iterators to transition from pointing to a node in the tree to the `_end` node (eg operator++ on the last valid node) and back. (operator-- on the end iterator)

I would show how to adjust your current iterator code but you did not show your current implementation...

Comment: someone might include `*end()` into a bst, though I suppose we simply declare that to be undefined.

Comment: That is one of the perils of exposing internal data structure as member types. If there was an iterator type encapsulation then `operator*` could trap and report such accesses.

Answer (score 0):

As by its definition the sentinel end-node sits at the end of the "right bone" (the "always go right path"), it makes sense to keep track of whether we are on that path or not. If we are not, no special consideration is needed, as we are not going to encounter that sentinel node.

If we are, then we could check whether the current node has no right child. If so, then the current node is that sentinel node, and we should exit.

If the current node's right child is the sentinel node (by the same conditions), then we could deal with that in the second case (the case where the current node has no right child), but then also relocate the sentinel node to its new "home".

Some remarks about your code:

- You should not reference `root->parent` after having called `DeleteNode(root)` which presumably frees the memory associated to that pointer.
- I did not understand why a `node_type*` is assigned to a `value_type*`, so I just only used `node_type*`

Here is your code with the changes needed to detect and sageguard the sentinel end-node:

```
    node_type* ExtractHelper(node_type* root, Key key, boolean onRightBone) {
        // Also when on sentinel end node, we don't delete anything:
        if (root == nullptr || onRightBone && root->right == nullptr) { 
            return root;
        } else if (key < root->value) {
            // As we go left, we are no longer on the right-bone of the tree
            root->left = ExtractHelper(root->left, key, false);
        } else if (key > root->value) {
            root->right = ExtractHelper(root->right, key, onRightBone);
        } else {
            if (root->left == nullptr) {
                node_type* temp = root->right;
                if (temp) {
                    // The following should happen before calling DeleteNode
                    temp->parent = root->parent; 
                }
                DeleteNode(root);
                return temp;
            }
            // Also when right child is the sentinel, we treat it here:
            if (root->right == nullptr || onRightBone && root->right->right == nullptr) { 
                node_type* sentinel = root->right;
                node_type* temp = root->left; // temp is guaranteed to not be nullptr
                temp->parent = root->parent; // Do this before DeleteNode
                if (sentinel) { // The right child is the sentinel node
                    sentinel->parent = GetRightest(temp); // Similar function as GetLeftest
                    sentinel->parent->right = sentinel; // Re-attach the sentinel
                }
                DeleteNode(root);
                return temp;
            }
            // Here we are sure that root->right is not the sentinel node, 
            //     and so temp is neither
            node_type* temp = GetLeftest(root->right);
            root->value = temp->value;
            root->right = ExtractHelper(root->right, temp->value, false);
        }
        return root;
    }
```